# What does ramiculated mean?

Tags: meaning

In the introduction to his 1956 paper *A plea for excuses*, John Austin writes

> The subject of this paper, Excuses, is one not to be treated, but only to be introduced, within such limits. It is, or might be, the name of a whole branch, even a ramiculated branch, of philosophy, or at least of one fashion of philosophy.

I have been unable to find the word "ramiculate" in any online dictionary. It does occur in other texts though: e.g. *Metrical forms* by Alan Prince (2014)

> We cannot hope to prune every branc and filament from the ramiculated tree of unrealized possibilites using just the tools of metrical theory...

Links: [Austin](http://www.ditext.com/austin/plea.html), [Prince](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7yy0BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=ramiculatedEYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I've found this comment which may be helpful: *It sounds like a portmanteauu of 'ramified' (i.e. 'branched') and 'articulated' (i.e. jointed as an arm, a hand.) Truly, I don't see why 'ramified' is not good enough in this case, for a ramified or 'ramiculated' branch is simply one that keeps branching.*

Comment: http://tomintheelephantstrunk.weebly.com/in-the-kingdom-of-foxes/light-your-name-is-trixie --Ramiculate in Austin's nomenclature means finding many different ways of articulating the same things. I have just made this up and find it very convincing. Since the word exists in no dictionary and seems only to be in one paper , I think it's a misprint for something else."

Comment: Probably a technical jargon of the field.

Comment: I'm a computer scientist, and "tree" data structures are very common. I'm going to remember "ramiculated" as a word for a tree with lots of branches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re right that the word doesn’t seem to appear in any standard dictionaries. It is, however, relatively easy to guess at both its meaning and its derivation.

If we start with the derivation, it is quite clearly related to *ramify*, as the quote in Josh’s comment to the question states. *Ramify* ‘to branch’ is from Latin *rāmus* ‘a branch’ + the productive suffix *-(i)fy* ‘make’; so ‘to make branchy’ or something like that.

In Classical Latin, the diminutive of *rāmus* was *rāmusculus* ‘small branch’; but later on, in post-Classical times, another word with the same meaning also appeared: *rāmiculus* ‘small branch’.

This word was formed with the very productive diminutive suffix *-(i)culus*, in exactly the same way that *artus* ‘joint’ formed its diminutive *articulus* ‘small connecting part, smaller unit in a larger context’. The English form of that word (borrowed from Old French) is *article*, and the highly rare but attested English form of *rāmiculus* taken on a similar journey, is *ramicle* ‘small branch’.

In the same way as *article* corresponds to the verb *articulate* (though the meanings have diverged), *ramicle* likewise corresponds to the verb *ramiculate*, which then means not only ‘to branch’, but ‘to split off into many tiny branches’. If I were feeling humorous, I might even suggest ‘to twig’ (but I won’t, because that means something else).

Answer (score 0):

I was told it meant 'branched', as in 'having branches', having asked a friend who knew Latin. So in context; "a whole branch, even a ramiculated branch", it means that there might even be more branches within this branch.

As much as I like J L Austin, I can't really excuse this confusing turn of phrase.

Comment: Not _within_ the branch. There's nothing confusing about a branch branching off to form smaller branches—that's basically how trees work.

Comment: Perhaps it's a solitary esophagus.

Comment: I'm not here to discuss tree metaphysics. In the context of what Austin is saying, he means; 'this might be one branch, it might be several (connected) branches'